# Encrypted text to passed as id in the url in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, url, encryption

I am implementing email verification by sending email to user on registration. On successful registration a mail with link to  "http://mydomain.com/Account/Activate/EncryptedKeyID." Sometime i got '/' or special character that cant be passed to the url. So, I use HttpUtility.UrlEncode to encode. But this does not help. When I click on the email it gives IIS error because of extra slash in "http://mydomain.com/Account/Activate/JLU/YmtRdRAFmBdqhR7tnA==".  I have used Rijndael/AES for encrypt and decrypt.

My Questions are:
Should i go for another encryption method?
Is there any alternative?

thanks in advance for your time and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around, I find that HttpUtility.UrlEncode wont work for my case and i have to use HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode as it is safer for url. It does not contain any potentially dangerous character '+' and '/' chars with '-' and '_' instead. For my case i use   `var ativationLink=HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenEncode(Convert.FromBase64String(Rij.Encrypt(param)));` for link to add in email.

And to retrieve original param i used

```
 var param= Rij.Decrypt(Convert.ToBase64String(HttpServerUtility.UrlTokenDecode(ActivationKey)));
```